# Federal Income Taxes For Year of Divorce

Tags: united-states, income-tax, divorce

In March, my spouse and I happily divorced, coming to our own agreement and keeping the courts out everything (other than termination).  Since we were legally married for three months of 2015, how will income taxes work for 2015 - can we file separately and pay taxes separately, or do we have to file joint for the year, or joint for the partial year?

Situation is that we both have incomes, have financial accounts that we've always managed separately, which were divided by the individual account after the divorce, and have always had separate health plans for the five years we were married.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I remember that I was given the option to do either. We chose joint for the tax benifits. [ Side note: I still get error correction refund checks from the IRS from 4 years ago with both my ex-wifes name on it and mine. They're usually for like $1.57. I always make sure she gets her half of the windall :-)  ]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What matters is your marital status on December 31 of the year. Since you were not married on December 31, you must file as Single (or in some cases with a dependent, Head of Household).